# How to send data from android app to my local site?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have a local site like no server no nothing just the html, css, javascript files and i need to send data from an app in my phone created with android studio and display it on the site.I read that you can have a webserver and send data with the android/java tcp client to it but i cant find how to do it.So how can i approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using server-side programming languages.
You can receive  data using Api and display it on your web pages after saving it in the database.
To start, I suggest learning Php - Mysql , it's easier to understand and easier to implement

Answer (score 0):

you can send data from your android mobile to the server by using API such as REST and SOAP but you have to any of the server-side scripting languages like node PHP etc.. Please refer the tutorial point to get better ideas

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm